# What's wrong with this code (how to fix the overfull \hbox)?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, customize, overfull

I'm getting lots of "**overfull \hbox**" warnings during compilation of a large document, and apparently this is caused by the following ToC customization.  The compiled PDF output appears to be nice, but I would like to optimize the code and remove all the warnings and pesky overfull hbox messages.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize}%
    % Chapters modification in ToC :
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline}
    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em} %

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A second chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A third chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fourth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fifth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\end{document}
```

I added the `draft` option to the document class to see what may be the cause of the messages, but I don't know what to do next.  So what's wrong with the MWE code above?

Preview of what the code above is doing (the black rectangles are coming from the `draft` option in the document class):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tocloft` uses `\cftchapnumwidth` for a box containing the whole chapter number. Concrete it used the following definition:

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima % in case of chapters this is similar to \makebox[\cftchapnumwidth]
  {\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil \@cftasnumb}
```

You've set `\cftchapnumwidth` to 0. So the chapter number (with or without your change of `\cftchappresnum` and `\cftchapaftersnumb`) is always wider, which results in an overfull \hbox. If you don't want to ignore the warning, you can try to set the chapter number in a `\rlap` or a `\makebox[0pt][l]`. To do so, you could use a hack, but you should also know, that this hack could break in future:

```latex
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed any longer
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize}%
    % Chapters modification in ToC :
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\specialchapterintoc}% Warning: Using a command with argument is a hack only and would fail for long numbers
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline}
    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em} %

\newcommand*{\specialchapterintoc}[1]{\rlap{\chaptername\ #1}}
    
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A second chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A third chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fourth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fifth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\end{document}
```

Another suggestion would be to patch `\numberline` to not longer use a `\hbox` of zero width, if `\cftXnumwidth` is zero. Assuming, that a width of half of the line width would be enough:

```latex
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize}%
% Chapters modification in ToC :
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em} %
  
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/numberline/before}{%
  \ifdim \@tempdima=\z@ \@tempdima.5\linewidth\fi
}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A second chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A third chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fourth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fifth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\end{document}
```

This still uses internals of `tocloft`, but IMHO is much cleaner than the first suggestion.

Another suggestion would be to use a package, that supports line breaks after the number, e.g., [`tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic):

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  breakafternumber=true,% do a linebreak after the number
  entrynumberformat=\chapternumberwithprefix,% see definition below
  numwidth=.5\linewidth,% I think, this would be enough, but …
  dynnumwidth,% if not use the needed width.
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*{\chapternumberwithprefix}[1]{\chaptername\ #1}
% Following command replaces your redefinition of \cftsubsubsecfont:
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\normalfont\footnotesize\textsf
]{tocline}{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A second chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A third chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fourth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fifth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you're saying that the warnings are normal and could simply be ignored, and that there's no other way if we don't want to "hack"?

Comment: @Cham overfull hboxes are TeX's way of saying there's too much stuff on one line, and it can't find a good place to break the line. Its sister warning is the underfull hbox, where there's too *little* content on one line, and TeX needs to stretch the spacing to fill a line. The longer your document, the more certain you are to encounter one of these twins. Just by writing normal paragraphs of text, you may run into one of these warnings. So yes, they are (mostly) ignorable—within normal text, the overfull amount is typically only a fraction of a millimeter, and your eyes won't even notice.

Comment: @gz839918 In this case the overfull \hbox is large, but it is expected and harmless.

Comment: So this glitch should be ignored completely?  There isn't a proper solution to get the "Chapter" word in front of its number, and on a separate line?

Comment: Hmm, I'm perplexed by all this.  The solutions appear to be complicated, just to get rid of the overfull warnings.  I now believe it's better to just ignore the warnings and use the simplest code possible.  But I'll vote for your answer anyway.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
    {\setbox0\hbox{\cftchapfont\chaptername\ \kern\cftchapnumwidth}%
     \global\cftchapnumwidth\wd0}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline\mbox{}\kern-\cftchapnumwidth}
```

[image: TOC]

Full code with the above change:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize}%
    % Chapters modification in ToC :
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
    {\setbox0\hbox{\cftchapfont\chaptername\ \kern\cftchapnumwidth}%
     \global\cftchapnumwidth\wd0}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline\mbox{}\kern-\cftchapnumwidth}

% from original
%    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
%    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0em} %

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{A first chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A second chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A third chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fourth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\chapter{A fifth chapter}

\section{A section title}

Blabla

\end{document}
```